# VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Function not implemented on google colabe

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, google-colaboratory

i try to run the demo on google colab from this repository

> https://github.com/LeonLok/Deep-SORT-YOLOv4

but I find this error

> VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Function not implemented

when searching on google about this I understand the problem is related a bout the GPU and the ram
but I do now know how can I fix it.